# Is it possible to use RenderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync with a Grid not visible to the user?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a UWP Desktop application in which the user needs to include text in a MediaComposition. I'm using renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync to create images from the texts and then add them as Overlays in MediaComposition. The problem is that the rendered Grid is visible to users. Is it possible to render with a hidden object? Any help is most welcome. Thanks.

These are code snippets. There are several other UI elements on the page. The problem is the space taken up by the grid, which didn't need to appear.

```
            <Grid x:Name="grdTextToImageClips" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Width="280" Height="auto" >


                var tb = new TextBlock { Text = tbxTitle.Text, FontFamily = fontFamily, FontSize = 24, FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold, TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap };

                grdTextToImageClips.Children.Add(tb);

                RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
                await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(grdTextToImageClips);

                grdTextToImageClips.Children.Remove(tb);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use RenderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync with a Grid not visible to the user?

No, based on the document [RenderTargetBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap?view=winrt-20348#xaml-visuals-and-rendertargetbitmap-capture-capabilities), it is mentioned that **Content that's in the tree but with its Visibility set to Collapsed won't be captured**. In other words, if you set the visibility of the control to `Collapsed`, then you can't capture it.